# Querying multiple records using composite key in the mybatis

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mybatis, mybatis-mapper

I have a table with composite key. I want to query it in bulk in mybatis. Is it possible? if yes, how?

Table structure of table Foo with foo_id_1 and foo_id_2 as composite primary key.

```
{
 foo_id_1 uniqueIdentifier,
 foo_id_2 uniqueIdentifier,
 foo_name nvarchar
}
```

I will have a list of foo POJOs and I want to query them to check if they exist or not.
Below is for getting a single object

```
<select id="getFooList" resultMap="foo">
        SELECT
            f.foo_id_1,
            f.foo_id_2,
            f.foo_name
        FROM foo f
        WHERE f.foo_id_1 = #{foo_id_1} and f.foo_id_2 = #{foo_id_2}
    </select>

    <resultMap id="foo" type="Foo">
        <id property="fooId1" column="foo_id_1"/>
        <id property="fooId2" column="foo_id_2"/>
        <result property="fooName" column="foo_name"/>
    </resultMap>
```

But I want to fetch in bulk.
Corresponding SQL query would be

```
Select *
From foo
Where (foo_id_1 = '1a' and foo_id_2 = '1b') or
      (foo_id_1 = '2a' and foo_id_2 = '2b') or
      (foo_id_1 = '3a' and foo_id_2 = '3b');
```

Comment: With [`<foreach>`](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach), you can iterate the parameter (e.g. `List<Entry<String, String>>`) to build the condition.

Comment: Clause WHERE Col1 = # AND Col2 = #

Answer (score 0):

If your calling application can combine the keys into a single delimited string, the query can split the values back out into individual search values. Since your use case involves multiple key columns, you will need two different delimiters - one to separate tuples, and one to separate keys within a tuple.

For example, if you can build a parameter like:

```
DECLARE @SearchIDs VARCHAR(MAX) = '1a,1b;2a,2b;3a,3b'
```

The following will separate the keys and perform an efficient key lookup:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        MAX(CASE WHEN S2.ordinal = 1 THEN S2.value END) AS search_id_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN S2.ordinal = 2 THEN S2.value END) AS search_id_2
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@SearchIDs, ';', 1) S1
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(S1.value, ',', 1) S2
    GROUP BY S1.ordinal
) P
JOIN foo f
    ON f.foo_id_1 = P.search_id_1 and f.foo_id_2 = P.search_id_2
```

Sample results:

| search_id_1 | search_id_2 | foo_id_1 | foo_id_2 | foo_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 1b | 1a | 1b | A |
| 2a | 2b | 2a | 2b | CCC |
| 3a | 3b | 3a | 3b | EEEEE |

In you actual code, you should cast the `search_id_1` and `search_id_2` values to the proper data type.

```
        CAST(MAX(...) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS search_id_1,
        CAST(MAX(...) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS search_id_2
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_kwSWsLU).

Other more formal ways to pass multiple repeating values in a parameter  involve constructing XML or JSON, but sometimes a plain string is the simplest as long as you can guarantee that the values cannot themselves contain any delimiters.